# Mac not rendering font in browser

Tags: css, macos, font-face, webfonts

I have used KnockoutHTF30 font in stylesheet. It is loading fine on windows and linux machines. But on mac, it does not come up.

Here is my code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "KnockoutHTF93";
    src: local("KnockoutHTF93"), url("/fonts/Knockout-HTF93-UltmtHeviwt.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/Knockout-HTF93-UltmtHeviwt.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/Knockout-HTF93-UltmtHeviwt.svg#webfontpB9xBi8Q") format("svg");
}
```

I have also used this meta tag at top of page.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;' />
```

Its fine on windows and linux.
[image]
But on Mac its like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be a default font for Macs. Is the font installed on the machine you're testing on?